# Passing data on to packet for transmission using readstream

Tags: tinyos

I am using the readstream interface to sample at 100hz, I have been able to integrate the interface into Oscilloscope application. I just have a doubt in the way I pass on the buffer value on to the packet to be transmitted . Currently this is how I am doing it :

```
uint8_t i=0;
```

event void ReadStream.bufferDone( error_t result,uint16_t* buffer,          uint16_t count )

```
 {
 if (reading < count  ) 
 i++;
 local.readings[reading++] = buffer[i];
 }
```

I have defined a buffer size of 50, I am not sure this is the way to do it as I am noticing just one sample per packet even though I have set Nreadings=2.
Also the sampling rate does not seem to be 100 samples/second when I check.I am not doing something right in the way I pass data to the packet to be transmitted.

Comment: This question is completely unclear to me. What do you want to achieve? What do you exactly use? What did you try to do, and what problems did you encounter? Precisely, what is your question? By the way, the code you pasted seems to be incorrect as you assign an `i`-th element of a buffer each time an event is signaled to an `i - 1`-th element of some array, which is nowhere declared.

Comment: Ok, Basically what I am trying to do is to modify the oscilloscope application so that it can support readstream interface. This is how data is transmitted in the orignal oscilloscope file : event void Read.readDone(error_t result, uint16_t data) {
    if (result != SUCCESS)
      {
 data = 0xffff;
 report_problem();
      }
    if (reading < NREADINGS) 
      local.readings[reading++] = data;
  } I want to now pass the buffer as I am using readstream instead of the data variable in the original file. Not sure how to go about that.

Comment: I still don't understand. You want your application to **use** or somehow *provide* the `ReadStream` interface? Maybe you want the sensor driver to provide readings with the `ReadStream` instead of `Read`? However, if the sensor requires 17-milliseconds settling time for each reading, this is an upper bound for sampling frequency (about 58 Hz). You cannot exceed physical limitations!

Comment: Yes I want the sensor to provide readings with ReadStream interface instead of Read interface.Yes the 17ms ADC settling time is an constraint when using the read interface, when using the ReadStream interface though I am finding out that ReadStream uses a micro-second timer and is independent of the 17ms settling time of the ADC.I am not exactly sure how it gets around the settling time but currently I am able to go upto 150hz without much jitter. In previous articles though I have read that there have been instances when rates upto 750hz have been configured using micaZ motes.

Answer (score 0):

I think I need to clarify a few things according to your questions and comments.

Reading a single sample from an accelerometer on micaZ motes works as follows:

1. Turn on the accelerometer.
2. Wait 17 milliseconds. According to the ADXL202E (the accelerometer) datasheet, startup time is 16.3 ms. This is because this particular hardware is capable of providing first reading not immediately after being powered on, but with some delay. If you decrease this delay, you will likely get a wrong reading, however, the behavior is undefined, so you may sometimes get a correct reading or the result may depend on environment conditions, such as ambient temperature. **Changing this 17-ms delay to a lower value is certainly a bad idea.**
3. Read values (in two axes) from the Analog to Digital Converter (ADC), which as an MCU component that converts analog output voltage of the accelerometer to the digital value (an integer). The speed at which ADC can sample is independent from the parameters of the accelerometer: it is another piece of hardware.
4. Turn off the accelerometer.

This is what happens when you call `Read.read()` in your code. You see that the maximum frequency at which you can sample is once every 17 ms, that is, 58 samples per second. It may be even a bit smaller because of some overhead from MCU or inaccuracy of timers. This is true when you sample by calling `Read.read()` in a loop or every fixed interval, because this call itself lasts no less than 17 ms (I mean the delay between the command and the event).

What you may want to do is:

1. Turn on the accelerometer.
2. Wait 17 ms.
3. Perform series of reads.
4. Turn off the accelerometer.

If you do so, you have one 17-ms delay for a set of samples instead of such delay for each sample. What is important, these steps have nothing to do with the interface you use for performing readings. You may call `Read.read()` multiple times in your application, however, it cannot be the same implementation of the `read` command that is already implemented for this accelerometer, because the existing implementation is responsible for turning on and off the accelerometer, and it waits 17 ms before reading each sample. For convenience, you may implement the `ReadStream` interface instead and call it once in your application.

Moreover, you wrote that `ReadStream` used a microsecond timer and is independent from the 17-ms settling time of the ADC. That sentence is completely wrong. First of all, you cannot say that an interface uses or does not use a timer. The interface is just a set of commands and events without their definitions. A particular implementation of the interface may use timers. The `Read` and `ReadStream` interfaces may be implemented multiple times on different platforms by various hardware components, such as accelerometers, thermometers, hygrometers, magnetometers, and so on. Secondly, the 17-ms settling time refers to the accelerometer, not the ADC. And no matter which interface you use, `Read` or `ReadStream`, and which timers a driver uses, milli- or microsecond, **the 17-ms delay is always required after powering on the accelerometer**. As I mentioned, you probably want to make this delay once per multiple reads instead of once per a single read.

It seems that the TinyOS source code already contains an implementation of the accelerometer driver providing the `ReadStream` interface which allows you to sample continuously. Look at the `AccelXStreamC` and `AccelYStreamC` components (in *tos/sensorboards/mts300/*).

The `ReadStream` interface consists of two commands. `postBuffer(val_t *buf, uint16_t count)` is called to provide a buffer for samples. In the accelerometer driver, `val_t` is defined as `uint16_t`. You may post multiple buffers, one by one. This command does not yet start sampling and filling buffers. For that purpose, there is a `read(uint32_t usPeriod)` command, which *directs the device to start filling buffers by sampling with the specified period* (in microseconds). When a buffer is full, you get an event `bufferDone(error_t result, val_t *buf, uint16_t count)` and a component starts filling a next buffer, if any. If there are no buffers left, you get additionally an event `readDone(error_t result, uint32_t usActualPeriod)`, which passes to your application a parameter `usActualPeriod`, which indicates an actual sampling period and may be different (especially, higher) from a period you requested when calling `read` due to some hardware constraints.

So the solution is to use the `ReadStream` interface provided by `AccelXStreamC` and `AccelYStreamC` (or maybe some higher-level components that use them) and pass an expected period in microseconds to the `read` command. If the actual period is lower than one you expect, this means that sampling at higher rate is impossible either due to hardware constraints or because it was not implemented in the ADC driver. In the second case, you may try to fix the driver, although it requires good knowledge of low-level programming. The ADC driver source code for this platform is located in *tos/chips/atm128/adc*.